# Help on Generating function - Analysis of Median of three - Quick Select

Tags: generating-functions, recursive-algorithms

I am trying to find out the average case analysis of median of 3 - quick select. The recurrence relation is 
\begin{equation}
C_{n,j} = 1 + \sum_{k=1}^{j-1}\pi_{n,k}C_{n-k,j-k} + \sum_{k=j+1}^{n} \pi_{n,k}C_{k-1,j}
\end{equation}
where
$$\pi_{n,k} = \frac{(n-k)(k-1)}{{{n}\choose{3}}}.$$

First we consider
$$C_j(x) = \sum_{n} C_{n,j}x^n.$$
Multiplying by ${{n}\choose{3}}\;  x^{n-3}$ and summing over $n$ on both sides
$$\sum_{n\geq 3}{{n}\choose{3}} x^{n-3}\; C_{n,j}
=\sum_{n\geq 3}{{n}\choose{3}}(1+\sum_{k=1}^{j-1}\pi_{n,k}C_{n-k,j-k} + \sum_{k=j+1}^{n} \pi_{n,k}C_{k-1,j} )\; x^{n-3} $$ 
We expand out the binary coefficients, since ${n\choose 3}=n(n-1)(n-2)/6$, so we get
$$\begin{aligned}\frac{1}{6} &\; \sum_{n\geq 3}n(n-1)(n-2) \;x^{n-3}\; C_{n,j}\\
&=\sum_{n\geq 3} \frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{6} x^{n-3} +\sum_{n\geq 3} \sum_{k=1}^{j-1}(k-1)(n-k)C_{n-k,j-k}x^{n-3} \\
&\qquad+\sum_{n\geq 3} \sum_{k=j+1}^{n} (k-1)(n-k)C_{k-1,j}\; x^{n-3}\end{aligned} $$
But look, the left hand side is precisely
$$\frac{1}{6} \sum_{n\geq 3}n(n-1)(n-2) \;x^{n-3}\; C_{n,j}=\frac{C^{'''}_{j}(x)}{6}$$
so we have
$$ \begin{aligned}
1/6 C_j^{'''}(x)  
&= \sum_{n\geq 3} n(n-1)(n-2)/6\; x^{n-3} +\sum_{n\geq 3} \sum_{k=1}^{j-1}(k-1)(n-k)C_{n-k,j-k}x^{n-3} \\
&\qquad+\sum_{n\geq 3} \sum_{k=j+1}^{n} (k-1)(n-k)C_{k-1,j}\; x^{n-3} \\
&= 1/6\; \sum_{n\geq 3} n(n-1)(n-2)\; x^{n-3} \rightarrow (1)\\
&\qquad  +\sum_{n\geq 3} \sum_{k=1}^{j-1}(k-1)(n-k)C_{n-k,j-k}x^{n-3} \rightarrow (2)\\
&\qquad +\sum_{n\geq 3} \sum_{k=j+1}^{n} (k-1)(n-k)C_{k-1,j}\; x^{n-3} \rightarrow (3) \end{aligned}$$

Lets solve each parts named $(1), (2)$ and $(3)$ separately.
$$\tag{1}
 \sum_{n\geq 3} n(n-1)(n-2)\; x^{n-3} = \frac{d^4}{dx^4}\sum_{n\geq 0} x^{n} = \frac{d^4}{dx^4} (\frac{1}{(1-x)}) = \frac{6}{(1-x)^4}  $$

The second term (2)
$$\tag{2}
\sum_{n\geq 3} \sum_{k=1}^{j-1}(k-1)(n-k)C_{n-k,j-k}x^{n-3} = $$ 
Since, $C_j(x) = \sum C_{n,j}x^n$  we have
      $C_{j-k}(x) = \sum C_{n,j-k}x^n$ 
      or  $C_{j-k}(x) = \sum C_{n-k,j-k}x^{n-k}$ 
      This term,$ \sum_{n\geq 3}(n-k)C_{n-k,j-k}x^{n-3} $ can be rewritten as $\sum_{n\geq 3}(n-k)C_{n-k,j-k}x^{n-k}\;x^{k-3} = x\; C_{j-k}^{'}\;x^{k-3} =C_{j-k}^{'}\;x^{k-2}$
       $\sum_{n\geq 3} \sum_{k=1}^{j-1}(k-1)(n-k)C_{n-k,j-k}x^{n-3} = \sum_{k=1}^{j-1} (k-1)x^{k-2}C_{j-k}^{'}\;$

The third term (3) is
$$\begin{aligned}
\sum_{n\geq 3} &\sum_{k=j+1}^{n}& (k-1)(n-k)C_{k-1,j}\; x^{n-3} \\
&= \sum_{n\geq 3} \sum_{k=1}^{n} (k-1)(n-k)C_{k-1,j}\; x^{n-3} \;\rightarrow (3.1)\\
&\qquad - \sum_{n\geq 3} \sum_{k=1}^{j} (k-1)(n-k)C_{k-1,j}\; x^{n-3}\; \rightarrow (3.2)\end{aligned}$$
We have
$$\tag{3.1} \sum_{n\geq 3} \sum_{k=1}^{n} (k-1)(n-k)C_{k-1,j}\; x^{n-3} = \sum_{n\geq 2} \sum_{k=1}^{n} (k-1)(n+1-k)C_{k-1,j}\; x^{n-2}$$
      Here, $a = k-1, b = n+1 -k ;\;a+b = n $ 
      $=1/x^2\;\sum_{n\geq 0} \sum_{a+b=n} (a)(b)C_{b,j}\; x^{n}  = 1/x^2 \;[\sum_{a\geq 0} a\;x^a] \;[\sum_{b\geq 0} bC_{b,j}\;x^b ]$ 
      $= 1/x^2 \; x \frac{d}{dx} \frac{1}{(1-x)} \; x \; \frac{d}{dx}\sum_{b=1}^{\infty} C_{b,j} \;x^b $ 
      Since, $C_{b,j} x^b = C_j$ 
      hence, $ = \frac{C^{'}}{(1-x)^2} $

{3.2}:
      How can we solve this? 
      $\sum_{n\geq 3} \sum_{k=1}^{j} (k-1)(n-k)C_{k-1,j}\; x^{n-3} = $